# Printing all records of a student who failed one subject

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a usecase on my studies for below example,
i am struggling with the logic on how i can do a select statement to get all the records to display a student who failed in one or more subject

Assuming i have below table

| Student_id | name | subject | marks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| s1 | adam | english | 35 |
| s1 | adam | math | 69 |
| s1 | adam | science | 55 |
| s2 | bob | english | 56 |
| s2 | bob | math | 76 |
| s2 | bob | science | 88 |
| s3 | pop | english | 33 |
| s3 | pop | math | 90 |
| s3 | pop | science | 76 |

Expected output should be

| Student_id | name | subject | marks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| s1 | adam | english | 35 |
| s1 | adam | math | 69 |
| s1 | adam | science | 55 |
| s3 | pop | english | 33 |
| s3 | pop | math | 90 |
| s3 | pop | science | 76 |

I have tried with this below query but it displaying none value

```
select count(*) 
from (select student_id 
      from student 
      where marks < 50 
      group by student_id 
      having count(subject) > 1) as dt
```

Comment: Your are selecting `count(*)`, this can not result in a table, but will result in one value.

Comment: You do `where marks < 50`. How do you expect `adam math 69` to be in your results?

Comment: @Luuk he wants all the records of the student who failed at least one subject

Answer (score 2):

I think something like this would work and is pretty simple:

```
Select * 
  From student 
  Where student_id In (Select Distinct student_id 
                         From student 
                         Where marks < 50);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `SUM OVER()` clause as follows :

This does the group by Student_id. And it calculates the number of failed object using `SUM CASE` clause

```
with cte as (
  select *, sum(case when marks <50 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by Student_id) as failed
  from student
)
select Student_id, name, subject, marks
from cte
where failed >= 1
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/1wJ9WAm4)

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT *
FROM student_scores
WHERE Student_id IN (
  SELECT Student_id
  FROM student_scores
  WHERE marks < 40
  GROUP BY Student_id
  HAVING COUNT(*) >= 1
)
```

This query will first select all records from the marks table where the marks are less than 40. It will then group the records by Student_id and count the number of records in each group